# Salesforce APEX based sharing. Am I in the right direction?

Tags: security, salesforce, apex-code

We have a Salesforce app where we have some custom objects and want to expose the various custom object rcords to customers.

We need to ensure that customers can see only the records belonging to their Account. Because of the way these records are setup(owned by various system users at different levels of processing), we cannot use owner based sharing...and cannot use criteria based sharing since its not dynamic(I cant use criteria based sharing to say "Share this record with all customer portal users who belong to the same Account as the record" at runtime).

So I know I have to use Apex based sharing. I have read up on the sharing objects and the sharing table. But how would I approach this.

I can write a trigger which upon inserting will create a share object and get all userids who belong to the customer portal group and whose account equals the account of the record and associate them with the share object of the record.

But I feel this is overkill correct? Lets say there are 5 users from one of our customers and lets say there are 500 records created a day...that means 2500 share objects a day just for 1 customer...for 10 customers this can go upto 25000...and scale in this way...

Am I right here?

Another problem would be if a new person joined that customer team..unless another process updates the sharing on older records, he/she cannot see the older records.

So is there a better/elegant way to do this? I thought of adding a share object to the group...but there is just one group "Customer portal group" and how do I associate the group with the account of the users?

I will appreciate any thoughts about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at high-volume customer portal users.  They're much cheaper relative to standard customer portal users and should meet your needs.  Unlike regular users they have a totally different sharing concept.  In a nutshell if they own an object they can see, if not they can't.  You can then extend this based on whether a contact or account lookup on the object matches the logged in user.

Read up on this documentation:

- [License Types](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm) (scan to High Volume Customer Portal)
- [Granting High-Volume Portal Users Access to Records](https://cs12.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?loc=help&target=customer_portal_setting_light_users.htm#SharingSets&section=CustomerPortal) (login required)

Comment: Hi Ralph,Thanks a lot for your reply. I did read up on high volume users and thought that some of their limitations would not work wit my needs here. For example, I think we cannot use roles or apex based security with them. What if I need to group my users between people who can see one object but not the other?

Comment: Marking as answer...ended up going this route.

Comment: Yep, you don't get any of the standard sharing framework.  They have some basic stuff based on comparing the logged in users account or contact to the record they're trying to view.  Other than that you'll need to implement your own sharing model which also means you'll need to create a visualforce page for users to access the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups for sharing to avoid creating so many sharing records. You would have one group per account and one sharing record per account. Instead of managing thousands of sharing records you would have to manage hundreds of groups.
I haven't tried this approach with this many groups, but I read some time ago that it should work (someone posted using a LOT of groups for sharing). If you do try this, please tell us if it worked OK.